# DB2 connection libraries in Grails

Tags: dependencies, db2, grails-2.3

In my new grails application I have two different databases which is connecting by means of two different drivers.

- First one is connecting with oracle driver and
- Second one is connecting with IBM  DB2 driver

But both the databases are mutually different

```
for oracle
driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
```

and

```
for DB2 
driverClassName = "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"
```

For the first one, DB connection is completed successfully, But for DB2 connection I have added four libraries in `/grailsapp/lib/` manually (Copied from a previous application).

- db2java.zip
- db2jcc.jar
- db2jcc4.jar
- db2jcc_license_cu.jar

But I need to add the libraries as dependency modules in BuildConfig.groovy

How can I add these libraries. Please anyone help me to find the correct path for adding the dependencies.